# Bitwise operations on 128 bit in java

Tags: java, ipv6

I have binary representation of two IPv6 addresses

For example:
First String is binary representation of

```
'2001:4E8:0:4000:0:0:0:0'
'00100000000000010000010011101000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

Second string binary representation

```
 '0:0:0:0:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff'
 '00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111'
```

Now I want to do a biwise 'AND' operation on the IPv6 Address and its mask.
What would be a good way to achieve this in java?

P:S: Integer.parseInt supports only 32 bit operations

Comment: consider using `BigInteger` or two `long`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `BigInteger`'s `and()` :

```
BigInteger first = new BigInteger("00100000000000010000010011101000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",2);
BigInteger second = new BigInteger("00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111",2);
BigInteger and = first.and(second);
```

Comment: simple and perfect

Answer (score 2):

You can use BitSet for this. But for this you will need to convert String to array of bytes

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(String bytes){
    byte[] bb = new byte[bytes.length()/8];
    byte m1 = (byte) (1 << 7);
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < bb.length; i++, j=i*8){
        byte b = bytes.charAt(j) == '1' ? m1 : 0;
        b |= Byte.valueOf(bytes.substring(j + 1, j + 8), 2);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(b));
        bb[i] = b;
    }
    return bb;
}
```

Now you can use it in BitSet

```
BitSet bs1 = BitSet.valueOf(toByteArray("00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"));
BitSet bs2 = BitSet.valueOf(toByteArray("00100000000000010000010011101000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"));
BitSet bs3 = bs1.and(bs2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you started out with the IPv6 address and netmask in standard IPv6 notation ... not in a binary string representation consisting of `'0'` and `'1'` characters.

If you use `InetAddress.getByName(String)` on an IPv6 address literal, you will get an `Inet6Address` object.  If you call `getAddress()` on this, you will get the raw address as a `byte[]`.  You can do the same to get a `byte[]` from a netmask.

Then you can loop over the respective byte arrays and use bitwise operations on them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion.